# Creating base in mem sql

Tags: singlestore

When I create data base in MEMSQL with the name "evento" for example, it create two others bases automatically, "evento_0" and "evento_1", and if I exclude, the querys in data base "evento" throws error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is your question?

When you create a database evento, you will see databases evento_0 etc - they are the partition databases - but users should not see or query those databases, as they exist on the leaves only.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your connecting to a leaf node in your cluster instead of to an aggregator node.   Those partition database (_XXX databases)  appear on leaves only.  Check the connection string your using for workbench.  You should point it at the host/port of an aggregator node.  Check memsql-ops list output to see which nodes are aggregators.

Comment: Thanks Adam I understand now.